# How to adjust sin (x) graph coordinates in java to fill only a portion of the window

Tags: java, graph, trigonometry

so currently I am working on a project for class in which I am required to draw the sin(x) function via the drawLine() method. Currently this is the loop I am using to achieve this:

```
    int xShift = getWidth() / 50;
    int xShift2 = getWidth() / 100;
    int yShift = getHeight() / 10;
    int yShift2 = getHeight() / 17;
    int xStart = xShift;
    int xEnd = xShift;
    int yStart = getHeight() / 2;
    int yEnd = getHeight() / 2;
    int scale = getHeight() / 2;

    for (double i = Math.PI / 32; i <= Math.PI * 2; i+= Math.PI / 32){
        xEnd += getWidth() / 64;

        yEnd = scale - ((int) Math.round(Math.sin(i) * scale));


        g.drawLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
        xStart = xEnd;
        yStart = yEnd;
    }
```

This outputs something that looks like this:

[image]

What I want to change is that the graph will be within the constraints of the dashed blue lines, and it also will go to the end of the grey line where the 2pi marker is (marked by the blue arrow). How can I go about making these changes?

Note: this is what it looks like when I maximize the window: [image]

For some reason the sin graph goes beyond the bounds I want it to.

Thank you for your time and I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: Reduce the available height and width by the amount you need.  Offset the start x/y by half the margin

Comment: Consider using dots instead of lines, simpler and faste. As long as you have at least one dot per pixel it will be continuous.

Comment: Well whatever calculation you use for the y-axis, use that to bound the height.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's see what you are doing with your calculation of Y.

```
    yEnd = scale - ((int) Math.round(Math.sin(i) * scale));
```

Since the actual sine function goes between -1 and 1, it means that your `yEnd` will go between `scale - scale` and `scale + scale`. This means it will go between 0 (the edge of the window), and 2×scale. Since your scale is half the height of the window, 2×scale means the full height of the window. Again - the edge of the window.

First, think what happens if your scale is smaller. If instead of height/2, the scale is (height/2 - 10), then 2×scale will be the window height - 20. That's more or less the amplitude you want - but it still scale - scale, so it still starts from the edge (try it!). Reducing scale further will lower the amplitude, but still, you will start from the edge.

To prevent that, you should change the formula. It shouldn't be adding the sine to `scale`. Think: when the sine is -1, you want it to be at the greatest distance from *the middle of the window*. When it's +1, you want the line to be at the greatest distance, again, from *the middle of the window*. Now that you changed `scale`, it's no longer half the height of the window, so you shouldn't use it for your base line.

You should have one parameter that says "what is the base height of my graph", and one parameter that says "what is the maximum amplitude of my graph". The two parameters shouldn't be the same:

```
int baseHeight = getHeight() / 2;
int amplitude  = getHeight() / 2 - getHeight() / 50;

...

// In the loop
yEnd = baseHeight + ((int) Math.round(Math.sin(i) * amplitude));
```

Play around with these parameters and you'll see how they affect the way your graph is drawn.

Now as for your X. You want to do 64 steps that represent 2π. But if you want the graph to be less wide than the window, the step size cannot be `getWidth() / 64`. You start `width/50` from the edge, add `63 * getWidth() / 64` to that. Since `width/50` is more than `width/64`, you will be drawing more than your width.

So you need to calculate the actual final width of the graph: It's supposed to be the total width, excluding the right and the left margins. So `getWidth() - 2 * getWidth()/50` is the actual width, and each step should be 1/64 of *that*.

```
int step = ( getwidth() - getWidth() / 25 ) / 64;

...

// In the loop
xEnd += step;
```